# Is there a way to read data from socket when the data does not end with a new line?

Tags: java, android, json, sockets, client

I have a bit of a problem. I have been working on an app that collects pollution data from a sensor. First I connect the phone to the sensor via WiFi direct, the sensor is the group host. But when I am supposed to read the data from the socket I have a problem. The data does ( which is JSON)  not end with a newline. So I can not use

```
mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
```

since it gets stuck. How can I read the data when it ends with no new line? The sensor sends data every 2 minutes so I need to return a new string every time the data is being sent. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

**EDIT** Tried this

```
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String terminator = "}}";
                int c;

                while((c = mBufferIn.read()) != -1) {
                    char character = (char) c;

                    if (String.valueOf(character).contains(terminator)==false) {

                        sb.append(character);


                    } else {
                        mServerMessage = sb.toString();
                        sb=null;
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }
                }

             }
```

Comment: You can read as many bytes with one read() as you want. Even one. Is it complicated json? If not then read until the closing }. Or does the json text have a fixed length?

Comment: The json looks like this {"d":{"temp_mc":33416,"...",..more data..}} I am not very familiar with working with json so I am not sure what complicated implies. I guess it is not. @greenapps

Comment: Is there a way to know how many bytes I would read each time new data comes? And for each new data that arrives, would the old data be removed? Or do I have to keep track how many bytes I have read before?@greenapps

Comment: Maybe you can read until the two successive }}'s at end of json text. Check if they do only occur at end.

Comment: So read one byte at the time and collect them in a string. Stop at }}.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the data will come in that exact format, the above may work, but keep in mind that JSON can come in many forms. `"This for instance is valid JSON without a single curly brace"`

Comment: How can I see if sb contains }} in the edit above? I tried to do what you said @greenapps

Comment: @Stephen I can guarantee that the data comes in this form everytime.

Comment: You are now checking if one character contains the two }}. Admit that it wil never do! Please rethink. Its not that difficult ;-).

Comment: @greenapps you are right, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you tried with "}}" is bound to fail because you're comparing it with ONE character, and "}}" are TWO characters.

I guess the more reliable way would be for you to count the open brackets and match that with the closing ones.

Something like this:

```
private static final char OPEN = '{';
private static final char CLOSE = '}';

int openCount = 0;
int closeCount = 0;

... read the char and add to the string builder and then ...

   if(character == OPEN) {
      openCount++;
   } else if(character == CLOSE) {
      closeCount++;
      if(closeCount == openCount) {
          ... this means it's over, you can process the message
      }
   }
```

Comment: I would have used one counter variable instead of two. Increment the count on an open brace, and decrement it on a closing brace. Process and clear the data when the counter falls to 0.